# How to Refresh Page after navigate back. OnAppearing is not called

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, navigation, back

On my MainPage I load the current element and display data such as a card.
The user can use PushAsync to navigate to the detail or edit page and update the data.

Returning from the navigation bar does not call OnAppearing, so I can not refresh the map (set location).

The way can look like this:
MainPage> DetailPage> EditPage

```
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  SetLocation();
}

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
  base.OnAppearing();

  var vm = BindingContext as MainViewModel;
  await vm?.InitializeAsync(null);

  SetLocation();
}

void SetLocation()
{
  try {
    var location = (BindingContext as MainViewModel).Location;

    if (location == null) {
      location = DataObjects.Location.Parse(AppSettings.Current.FallbackMapsLocation);
    }

    var initialPosition = new Position(
        location.Latitude,
        location.Longitude);

    var mapSpan = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
        initialPosition,
        Distance.FromMiles(1.0));

    Map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
  }
  catch (FeatureNotSupportedException) {
  }
}
```

From the EditPage I navigate back twice (DetailPage and then MainPage). 
My object itself is up to date and gets the changes via OnPropertyChanged, so I have the current location as well.

Should I use MessagingCenter or are there other / better options?
Xamarin Forms version is 4.0 and I use shell

Comment: you really didn't include enough code to illustrate how you're passing data around.  If you use databinding and INPC then generally the UI should update itself when the data changes.

Comment: you can use onDisappearing() method of the detail page. and reload the data. make your set location method static and call that from detail onDisappearing()

Comment: @Jason: i use databinding, but the Map does not have a property for the current location

Comment: ah, ok - then I would probably use MessagingCenter to do it

Comment: Ok, thank you, Jason!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use an event if you want to trigger some commands when the navigation comes from the next page.

Firstly, define an event in your `DetailPage`:

```
public delegate void UpdateLocation(string info);
public event UpdateLocation UpdateLocationEvent;
```

Then register this event when you pushed:

```
var detailPage = new DetailPage(new DetailViewModel(item));
detailPage.UpdateLocationEvent += (info) =>
{

};
await Navigation.PushAsync(detailPage);
```

At last, you can call this event to trigger the code block in the MainPage. i.e. in the detail page's disappearing event:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

    UpdateLocationEvent?.Invoke("location info");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip
I now use a combination of MessagingCenter and Delegates

Comment: @jckruse Glad you solved it. If you felt this helpful, please accept this as an answer.